# How to skip ( and ) while using textscan?

Tags: matlab, textscan

I'm trying to read numbers in a text file line by line. Each line in the file is like this:

> (563,478),(630,573),1

I tried the command below but it didn't work:

```
textscan(f1, '%d%d%d%d%d', 'delimiter', ',');
```

How can I skip the **")"** and **"("**?  I want to read only the numbers.

[Here](http://s8.picofile.com/file/8289965234/005.txt.html) is one of the text files. (the red button)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
textscan(f1, '(%d,%d),(%d,%d),%d')
```

to scan a file or

```
sscanf(f1, '(%d,%d),(%d,%d),%d')
```

to scan a string.

Usage(tested in Octave):

```
f1 = fopen('005.txt','r');
c=textscan(f1, '(%d,%d),(%d,%d),%d');
fclose(f1);


f1 = '(401,596),(443,636),1'
sscanf(f1,'(%d,%d),(%d,%d),%d')
```

Comment: I tried what you suggest, but the result is the same as before. A 1x5 cell array in which all elements are like []. I think they are all empty.

Comment: @HadiGhahremanNezhad  Format of the file may not be one that you assumed. You may upload the file.

Comment: thanks @SardarUsama, but when I use `cell2mat` on the result, the output is an empty array with 1 element. I think the `textscan` is not reading the file correctly.

Comment: @rahnema1 thank you, the format of all the files is **.txt** . I will upload one of them in the question.

Comment: @HadiGhahremanNezhad I opened the file,no problem can be seen!

Comment: @SardarUsama I tested in Octave. can you test `sscanf('(401,596),(443,636),1','(%d,%d),(%d,%d),%d')`  ?

Comment: I now understand the mistake here. The OP is doing this: `sscanf('005.txt', '(%d,%d),(%d,%d),%d')`

Comment: @SardarUsama I added some usage examples.

Comment: instead of `fopen` and `fclose`, you can also use `fileread`. Although it is fine as it is

Comment: @SardarUsama Good suggestion.

Comment: @SardarUsama and @rahnema1 thank you both. The `textscan` worked fine. The problem was with the `fopen` and `fclose`.